# How to get rid of a "get element" inside a loop in a Lightning flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I am new to Lightning flow and I am running into an error. I have a list of records (for a custom object called assignment) and for each assignment record, I need to get a contact record whose id matches this assignment record's "Resource" field. Then I need to send an email to this list of contacts. The flow looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, I have a get element inside of a loop, which is a really bad practice. I am not sure how to get rid of this get element inside a for loop situation. Can someone please help?
Thank you

Comment: i would look at [UnofficialSF](https://unofficialsf.com/flow-actions/) which has a bunch of components that can do filtering on collections - this should let you do one query to get all Resources at once then filter them into only the resources per assignment so you can send the emails (essentially Flow actions that do what you can do with apex maps)

Comment: which flow action did you have in mind for this?

Comment: FilterCollection

Comment: You are right that a GET in a Loop like this is bad practice and we often find ourselves needing to build apex or install tools such as the one suggested from UnofficialSF. On occasion, though, we may find a clever way out, but it depends on the details. Could you update your question with the answer to the following questions? You mention the Assignment records have a "Resource" field that you're using to find the Contact. Is that "Resource" field a lookup to Contact? And which email action is that you are using at the end?

Answer (score 0):

THE loop in the flow is working as for each loop and you must not add get element inside loop

Take one collection and add your ids to that collection and than fetch the record

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).